# Add brim everywhere, not just around the outermost line

Tags: slic3r, brims

I have a repair part that I need to print with ABS and I know that I have warping problems with ABS.

I'm now trying to mitigate this by printing a circle around my object and use more brim. You can consider this as a manually designed skirt, but I want the brim to be on both sides of the skirt.

However, when slicing the repair part with the ring, I get brim only outside the "skirt", not inside of it.
How would I get brim also in the area marked here?

[image: Add brim here]

Answer (score 1):

When there's a cut in the outer ring (the manual skirt), Slic3r will fill the area as expected:

[image: Brim in the gap]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Prusa Slicer 2.2.0 in print settings
skirt and brim, set distance from object to zero

Other slicers should have same capability. As long as you have two parts on the bed that are not distinctly separated, you'll get only one brim.

Comment: I have installed 2.2.0 alpha, but that setting does not help

Comment: It's the two part aspect that's causing the problem. Move the outer ring off the bed and print it separately.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If I print it separately, the ring will no longer help against warping of the main part.